# Import Numpy library in flutter using starflut

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, flutter, opencv, dart

I want to run a python script in my flutter app. Thanks to [starflut](https://pub.dev./packages/starflut) package which helped to do this. Now I want to run a python script that uses NumPy and OpenCV libraries. I want to import these libraries into my python script. I researched a lot about how can I achieve this I couldn't find a way. So I'm posting here so that whoever got the solution for this problem can suggest to me how to do this.